# Accessing request middleware from inside models

Tags: node.js, express, model, request, middleware

When we setup a Node Express application, by default the main app.js file is created and two routes (index.js and users.js). The request middleware can be directly accessed from inside the routes folder.

```
//routes/index.js
const user = require('../models/users.js');
const createUser = user.createUser;

router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {
await craeteUser(req);
...
//I can get req.body.anything
})
```

Is there any way to access the reuest body inside models folder. (say) I have created a users model that has a function like this...

```
//models/users.js
async function createUser(req)
{
    ....
    //I cannot get req.body.anything
}

module.exports = {createUser}
```

Comment: You need to use body-parser.

Comment: body-parser is depreciated. It is now inbuilt within Express.

Comment: In that case you have to use app.use(express.json());